# Dragging and dropping a file on launcher icon does not raise the window in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, drag-and-drop

I know this is a possible duplicate but I do have not a convincing answer yet.

I initially did not like unity and did not switch to it till 12.04 (used gnome fallback). I have started using it only when 12.04 came out.

Here is the problem. Whenever I want to drag a file from one window to another(like nautilus to gmail in chrome or vlc playlist etc), I usually drag it to the taskbar/panel and wait for the destination window to raise/focus and then I drop the file. I have found this feature ever since I started using computers. Heck, even Windows 2000, XP could do it. Gnome could do it ever since I started using it (8.04 ubuntu).

It does not work with unity in 12.04.

I have had to install ugly xfce4-panel just for this purpose. But I am hardwired to first drag it to unity and then realize it does not work and then drag it to xfce4-panel.

Is there a possible workaround or a patch somebody has written that can I can install and not worry about it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu [bug 607796](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/607796) is about this.  The design team has approved for this behavior to be implemented in Unity.  But it has not been a priority, and has not been worked on yet, at least as visible from the bug report.  I'd recommend subscribing to that bug report, at the least.

I see that the most recommended practice here is [to close this question as off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs).  I see that happened to [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84744/launcher-does-not-pop-out-a-running-app-when-dragging-a-file-to-it).  I'm going to leave that to more experienced Ask Ubuntu users.  Thanks.